# Android Geofencing in Nativescript. Background Event causes java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: android, geolocation, nativescript, background-process, geofencing

so my goal is to create a nativescript Plugin that allows the developer to set a geofence anywhere, which will trigger even when the app was closed (swiped away) by the user. I have a working example when the app is in the foreground or when the app is just hidden. 
I also successfully receive a trigger event, even when the app is fully closed, however this leads to the following exception:

n uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to instantiate receiver carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'carTabako/GeofenceBroadcastReceiver'

```
StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'carTabako/GeofenceBroadcastReceiver'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3489)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1759)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                                    Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'carTabako/GeofenceBroadcastReceiver'
                                        at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstanceNative(Native Method)
                                            at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstance(Runtime.java:777)
                                                at com.tns.Runtime.initInstance(Runtime.java:750)
                                                    at carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.<init>(GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.java:13)
                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                            at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(AppComponentFactory.java:84)
                                                                at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(CoreComponentFactory.java:56)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3482)
                                                                        ... 8 more
```

I suspect an issue in one of the two AndroidManifest.xml files, as there is one for the actual application under *application-name/App_resources/Android/src/AndroidManifest.xml*
and then there is one just for the plugin in: *src/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml*

Here is the relevant part of the manifest for the (demo) application, i cloned from nativescript (demo-angular):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
            <!-- GEOFENCING Receiver    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
```

And this is the manifest from the plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <application>
           <receiver
            android:name="carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
   </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see i am already playing around with the plugin manifest. I register the receiver twice, which does not make any difference. I am still not sure which manifest is relevant in the end, as there is no clear documentation about it. 
I would love to hear your thoughts, where my issue could come from and how to fix it.

Edit: Here is the implementation of my BroadcastReceiver:
It has a lot of logging and a file creation system to keep track if the event fires in the background/when closed.

```
module carTabako {

        @JavaProxy("carTabako.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver")
        export class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

            public onReceive(context, intent) {

                console.log("INTENT IN Receiver: ", intent);
                let geofencingEvent =  com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
                if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                    console.log("Error with the geofencing Event: "+geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
                    return;
                }
                const directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
                const path1 = path.join(directory.toString(), "Geofences");
                const folder = Folder.fromPath(directory);

                let file = folder.getFile("geofenceFile"+ new Date().toString());
                        file.writeText("some random content;" + intent)
                            .then(result => {
                                file.readText()
                                    .then(res => {
                                        console.log("Successfully saved in " + file.path);
                                        console.log("read file: " + file.readTextSync());
                                    });

                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err);
                            });
                let geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
                dialogs.alert(""+ geofencingEvent).then(()=> {
                    console.log("Dialog closed!");
                });
                if (geofenceTransition == com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

                    // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
                    // multiple geofences.
                    let triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

                    // Get the transition details as a String.
                    let geofenceTransitionDetails =  triggeringGeofences.toString();

                    console.log("Transition received: ", geofenceTransitionDetails);
                } else {
                    console.log("event with no interest for us received");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your GeofenceBroadcastReceiver implementation.

Comment: @Manoj i updated the question. FYI: Everything is within the same file geolocation.android.ts

Comment: Did you include this file `geolocation.android.ts` in webpack config?

Comment: So the plugin code does not have a webpack config that i can find. I did not include anything into the webpack.config from the main app. Should I include it somewhere in the main app?

Comment: Can you show your plugin source structure? Do you have a Git repo? To answer about webpack config, generally you would ask the user to do it in his webpack config as part of the plugin setup.

Comment: In terms of structure: I use the nativescript location plugin as basis and just started to add some code in the geolocation.android.ts
the structure is still the same

can you tell me where you would add the geolocation.android.ts in the webpack. I have no experience with webpack..

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it. 
VERY BIG THANKS TO [@Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060423/manoj) who saved me with his tip to add it into the webpack.config.js

For people finding this thread:
you have to add it into the webpack.config.js of the main plugin like this:

```
const appComponents = [
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    "nativescript-geolocation"
];
```

Just adding geolocation.android to it did not help, because there are quite some dependencies in the plugin from nativescript. if the file is completly stand-alone it should be fine though.

After that i had a java nullpointer exception when starting the app. That was caused by assigning the pendingIntent, which is required for geofencing in geolocation.android.ts too early (outside of any function). I moved it into the function where the pending intent is first needed and --> done :)

Thanks again to [@Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060423/manoj)